# How to stress-test a scalable cloud-based (AWS) product as it scales up from 100 to 1K or 10K connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, stress-testing

I am building a cloud based(AWS) product that captures, stores and disseminates video/images by means of APIs. I want to know as my product scales up from 100 connections to 1K to 10K and even 100K and much more, how do I stress test my product to ensure performance and minimum lag?

Also, I would like to have any practical tips as to how does one estimate the hardware requirement in AWS as the product scales up.

Comment: This is a vary vague question.  Do you already have the scaling setup created?  How are you scaling?  Cloudwatch or a custom internal method?   Do you want many concurrent API connections?  Should they be HTTP POST?  Do you upload files?  Do they download files?

Comment: Hi, I will be scaling horizontally. I am using cloudwatch. We've concurrent API connection and POST,GET,DELETE methods will be profusely used. We have APIs to upload and download files, do live streaming (video/audio) and much more.The question is that we are expecting our number of clients to grow exponentially once we launch our product. From the scale of 100 users to 1K to 10K in 5 to 10 months. I will be using jMeter to do stress testing but wanted to see if anyone here has better suggestions. Thanks